# Communicating with PHP from an android app without internet?

Tags: javascript, php, android, html, android-studio

I have made a web page and i am running it on a local host using the xampp server. In this web page I have a canvas that draws a line between two point. I read these points from a locally available csv file that I have generated. I would like to make an android application, where there is a provision to enter two numbers. I want this android application to make a csv file and save it on my computer so that I can access this file using my javascript.

**Note:** can I pass these values via an usb connected between the mobile and computer so that I can make a csv file locally in my computer? I want all of this to happen **without the requirement of internet connection.**

**PS:** I am newbie to android. If the above is possible, then please brief on how to approach this problem.

Comment: What has the PHP tag got to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a XAMP server all you need to do is connect the android device to the same network/router. There you can talk via HTTP methods to the apache server. You will just need to provide the ip address to the android app.

In the router you can set a static ip address for the mac address of your computer, so every time it connects to the router it always get the same IP and you dont need to input it again on the android app.